# Проблема с использованием символов Unicode в C#

Tags: c#, unicode

У меня возникла проблема с выводом символов Unicode, которые имеют длину кода больше четырех символов.

Дело в том, что при попытке вывести в `label1` символ Unicode-а, например, вот такой: `U+1F4BE`, программа почему то не захватывает последний символ. В данном примере это символ `E`.

[image: проблемный код с присвоением label1.Text значения U+1F4BE]
(не буду прикреплять весь код, ведь о большой, а проблема только с выводе символов)

Никак не могу понять в чем проблема, ведь с кодами по типу `U+2709` все прекрасно работает:

[image: код с присвоением label1.Text значения U+2709]

Также в начале кода написано следующее:

[image: код из начала]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставляйте код текстом, а не скринами в свои вопросы и ответы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В C# строки имеет кодировку по-умолчанию `UTF16` для Windows.

Ваш юникод представлен для `UTF32`, а не `UTF16`. В `UTF16` ваш юникод будет представлен двумя:

```
label1.Text = "\xD83D\xDCBE";
```

Чтобы не гуглить каждый раз перевод юникода из `UTF32` в `UTF16`, просто используйте [`char.ConvertFromUtf32(unicode)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.convertfromutf32?view=net-6.0).

Для вашего примера выйдет так:

```
label1.Text = char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F4BE);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @ДонБалон Пожалуйста)